# Load quick-load in roswell script

Tags: common-lisp

I am beginner of Common-Lisp, I created Common-Lisp project with Roswell.

I found Quickutil(http://quickutil.org/) and use it as below code.

```
#!/bin/sh
#|-*- mode:lisp -*-|#
#|
exec ros -Q -- $0 "$@"
|#
(progn ;;init forms
  (ros:ensure-asdf)
  (ql:quickload :quickutil :silent t)
  (qtlc:utilize
     :utilities '(:iota :riffle)
     :categories '(:alexandria)
     :symbols '(:split-sequence-if-not)))

(defpackage :ros.script.lbc.3744114298
  (:use :cl))
(in-package :ros.script.lbc.3744114298)

(defun main (&rest argv)
  (declare (ignorable argv))
  (princ (qtl:iota 5)))
;;; vim: set ft=lisp lisp:
```

run `./lbc.ros` will get below error.

```
Unhandled SB-INT:SIMPLE-READER-PACKAGE-ERROR in thread #<SB-THREAD:THREAD "main thread" RUNNING
                                                          {10005505B3}>:
  Package QTLC does not exist.

    Line: 22, Column: 15, File-Position: 461

    Stream: #<CONCATENATED-STREAM :STREAMS (#<SB-SYS:FD-STREAM for "file /Users/conao/.roswell/local-projects/lbc/src/lbc.ros" {1002EDF3A3}>
                                            #<SB-IMPL::STRING-INPUT-STREAM {1002EE1113}>) {1002EE3EF3}>

Backtrace for: #<SB-THREAD:THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {10005505B3}>
0: (SB-DEBUG::DEBUGGER-DISABLED-HOOK #<SB-INT:SIMPLE-READER-PACKAGE-ERROR "Package ~A does not exist." {1002F79883}> #<unused argument> :QUIT T)
1: (SB-DEBUG::RUN-HOOK *INVOKE-DEBUGGER-HOOK* #<SB-INT:SIMPLE-READER-PACKAGE-ERROR "Package ~A does not exist." {1002F79883}>)
...
```

small fix ptlc:utilize place.

```
#!/bin/sh
#|-*- mode:lisp -*-|#
#|
exec ros -Q -- $0 "$@"
|#
(progn ;;init forms
  (ros:ensure-asdf)
  (ql:quickload :quickutil :silent t))

(defpackage :ros.script.lbc.3744114298
  (:use :cl))
(in-package :ros.script.lbc.3744114298)

(defun main (&rest argv)
  (declare (ignorable argv))
  (qtlc:utilize
     :utilities '(:iota :riffle)
     :categories '(:alexandria)
     :symbols '(:split-sequence-if-not))
  (princ (qtl:iota 5)))
;;; vim: set ft=lisp lisp:
```

run small fix code as `./lbc.ros` will get below error.

```
Unhandled SB-INT:SIMPLE-READER-PACKAGE-ERROR in thread #<SB-THREAD:THREAD "main thread" RUNNING
                                                          {10005505B3}>:
  Symbol "IOTA" not found in the QUICKUTIL package.

    Line: 22, Column: 18, File-Position: 473

    Stream: #<CONCATENATED-STREAM :STREAMS (#<SB-SYS:FD-STREAM for "file /Users/conao/.roswell/local-projects/lbc/src/lbc.ros" {1002EDF3A3}>
                                            #<SB-IMPL::STRING-INPUT-STREAM {10019EB603}>) {1002EE3EF3}>

Backtrace for: #<SB-THREAD:THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {10005505B3}>
0: (SB-DEBUG::DEBUGGER-DISABLED-HOOK #<SB-INT:SIMPLE-READER-PACKAGE-ERROR "Symbol ~S not found in the ~A package." {100206D693}> #<unused argument> :QUIT T)
1: (SB-DEBUG::RUN-HOOK SB-EXT:*INVOKE-DEBUGGER-HOOK* #<SB-INT:SIMPLE-READER-PACKAGE-ERROR "Symbol ~S not found in the ~A package." {100206D693}>)
...
```

How to use Quikutil in Roswell script?

BTW, I can use Quickutil in Roswell REPL.

```
$ ros run
* (ql:quickload :quickutil :silent t)

(:QUICKUTIL)
* (qtlc:utilize
     :utilities '(:iota :riffle)
     :categories '(:alexandria)
     :symbols '(:split-sequence-if-not))
; compiling...

* (princ (qtl:iota 5))
(0 1 2 3 4)
(0 1 2 3 4)
```

Comment: Just in case, since you say yourself a CL beginner: you know you don't *need* to use Roswell for CL dev, right ? Regards

Comment: Roswell makes many things simplier. Why do you think it is not suitable for a beginner?

Comment: @AlexanderArtemenko I just say it is not a hard requirement, and it may be more complicated to setup and use (as shows this question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need it to move qtlc:utilize into a separate toplevel form, like that:

```
#!/bin/sh
#|-*- mode:lisp -*-|#
#|
exec ros -Q -- $0 "$@"
|#
(progn ;;init forms
  (ros:ensure-asdf)
  (ql:quickload :quickutil :silent t))

(qtlc:utilize
     :utilities '(:iota :riffle)
     :categories '(:alexandria)
     :symbols '(:split-sequence-if-not))

(defpackage :ros.script.lbc.3744114298
  (:use :cl))
(in-package :ros.script.lbc.3744114298)

(defun main (&rest argv)
  (declare (ignorable argv))
  (princ (qtl:iota 5)))
;;; vim: set ft=lisp lisp:
```

This way, when lisp will evaluate form

```
(qtlc:utilize
     :utilities '(:iota :riffle)
     :categories '(:alexandria)
     :symbols '(:split-sequence-if-not))
```

it will know about package `qtlc` because it was loaded by the previous form.

You also can leave call to qtlc:utilize but use uiop:symbol-call function to call it, like that:

```
#!/bin/sh
#|-*- mode:lisp -*-|#
#|
exec ros -Q -- $0 "$@"
|#
(progn ;;init forms
  (ros:ensure-asdf)
  (ql:quickload :quickutil :silent t)
  (uiop:symbol-call :qtlc :utilize
     :utilities '(:iota :riffle)
     :categories '(:alexandria)
     :symbols '(:split-sequence-if-not)))

(defpackage :ros.script.lbc.3744114298
  (:use :cl))
(in-package :ros.script.lbc.3744114298)

(defun main (&rest argv)
  (declare (ignorable argv))
  (princ (qtl:iota 5)))
;;; vim: set ft=lisp lisp:
```

Function `uiop:symbol-call` will resolve symbol `qtlc:utilize` in runtime after the `ql:quickload` finished it's work.

Comment: I don't see how moving the offending form to toplevel can make the `qtlc` package be available for it at read time.  Have you tried this?

Comment: @Svante: maybe the file is only loaded and not compiled?

Answer (score 2):

When you load a file, the toplevel forms first get read, then compiled, then loaded.  If reading one form depends on having loaded another, you need to evaluate that other one earlier.

Wrap such forms in an `eval-when`:

```
(eval-when (:compile-toplevel :load-toplevel :execute)
  (ros:ensure-asdf)
  (ql:quickload :quickutil :silent t))
```

Standard toplevel definition macros such as `defun` already expand to such a form so that you usually do not need to think about that.

Comment: This will not help.

Comment: @AlexanderArtemenko: care to elaborate?

Comment: Sure, see my answer above.